# Expectation for notification is fulfilled without invoking handler block

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase, xctestexpectation

In a unit test I have an expectation for notification which I provide to the method `waitForExpectation: timeout:`. The last one doesn't fail so the expectation is fulfilled. But the handler of the notification sometimes isn't being invoked. I know it because NSLog at the start of the handler isn't printed in this case.

```
XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationForNotification:NotificationName
                                                           object:object
                                                          handler: ^BOOL(NSNotification *notification) {
    NSLog(@"handler");
    <...>
}];

[self waitForExpectations:@[expectation] timeout:timeout];
```

How is it possible that the expectation is fulfilled, but its handler hasn't been invoked?

Comment: Because of the timeout https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500748-waitforexpectations

Comment: Actually the expectation isn't failed due to timeout, it's somehow successful before the timeout, but the handler isn't invoked.

Comment: Could you show real code that is reproducible, not a toy excerpt?